# Dialogflow Phone gateway Lists

Tags: dialogflow-es, telephony

I'm at an intermediate level of learning dialogflow.

My question is: Is there a way I can dictate a List to the user and make the user click a number on keypad and get the corresponding item?

Scenario:
Phone gateway bot: 1 - Chocolates, 2 - Flowers, 3 - Soccer
User: (Either says the option or types it in)

I've read in the documentation that we must have different paths for google home and google assistant. Found https://dialogflow.com/docs/integrations/telephony but I couldn't understand what "The intents in the sample use rich messages for telephony responses. These are the types you can use:"

Does it mean that in addition to rich responses you can use synthesize audio etc or does it mean that instead of rich responses you can use synthesize audio?

Just wondering if the scenario I'm looking for is possible or not....

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The features available in Telephony Gateway include: synthesize speech (SSML), playing audio, and call transfers. You can see more in Dialogflow's [Telephony sample](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-telephony-nodejs). What you can do is have multiple intents for each pathway your users would be selecting and have training phrases that would match expected user responses given a set of options. More reference docs are also available [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1#google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.Intent.Message.TelephonySynthesizeSpeech).